# Where to get data for all the country, province, city and zip code in the world?

Tags: javascript, c#, php, jquery

everyone.

I tried searching the internet but couldn't find an answer to the requirement that I must accomplish.

So my requirement is, I need to have a data of all the country, province, city and zip codes in the world.

There will be 4 drop down lists, one for each. so it looks like this.

First drop down for **Country**, when its value changed, the second drop down, which is the province will load all its data from all the provinces in the selected country.

Same goes for the third and fourth drop down list, if the **Province** drop down value changed, the city drop down will load all the values which is associated with the selected province. Then when the city drop down value changed, the zip code drop down will load all the values associated with its corresponding city.

So there will be 4 layers in total.

- Country
- Province
- City
- Zip Code

I searched the internet for two days and could not really find data that matched the requirement. Will be so much thankful if you could show me a link or an API that I can use.

Please note that I need the data for the whole world, I got no problem with its programming, you can refer me to an XML or JSON data format.

Answer (score 2):

you can use the google maps api for this:
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/intro

Comment: Well yeah, I'm having this as a last resort if I do not find a more specific source that matches my requirement. The problem is, it will consume me some time to study maps api as I have not used this before.